# Displaying records in table after join and group by a particular column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, group-by

I have two tables which contain some data :

Table1 : **abc**

```
||entity_id| entity_title|  cust_code| cust_acc_no     ||
----------------------------------------------------------
|| AB101Z  |   IND       |    101Z   |    1234         ||    
|| AB101Z  |   PAK       |    101Z   |    1357         ||    
|| CD101Y  |   IND       |    101Y   |    2468         ||
|| EF101X  |   IND       |    101X   |    3579         ||    
|| JK201N  |   LKO       |    201N   |    5678         ||
```

Table2 : **def**

```
||entity_title| in_count|  out_quant||
---------------------------------------------
|| IND        |   10    |       7   ||     
|| LKO        |    7    |       7   ||     
|| PAK        |    5    |       2   ||
```

joined Table : **abcdef**

```
||entity_id| entity_title|  cust_code ||      
--------------------------------------------------
|| AB101Z  |    INDPAK   |     101Z   || 
|| CD101Y  |    INDPAK   |     101Y   ||         
|| EF101X  |    INDPAK   |     101X   ||
```

I want to join tables **abc** and **def** which would be resultant in table **abcdef**.

While joining both tables and records would be grouped by `entity_title`. The joining condition would be such that `in_count!=out_count`.  For example, in such situation `LKO` as `entity_title` would not be part of resultant table.

I need to replace the `entity_title` records with matching condition by a third record signifying a matched record, for ex, `INDPAK` is the replacement for all the records whether those are for IND and PAK both or either of those two.

I tried to come up with a solution but was not able to form a single query.Thanks in advance for any solution suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution avoids hard-coding.  It comprises three steps:

- The first sub-query identifies common (ENTITY_ID, CUST_CODE) combinations for ENTITY_TITLEs with different counts.
- The second sub-query identifies the ENTITY_TITLEs which own those combos and derives a compound ENTITY_TITLE for them.  (It uses LISTAGG, which is an 11gR2 thing, but there are workarounds for string concatenation in earlier versions of the database).
- The outer query produces the required output, substituting the compound ENTITY_TITLE for the original ENTITY_TITLE.

Here is the whole thing.  I admit I don't like its reliance on DISTINCT clauses to get the required output but the joining rules produce unwanted duplicates.

```
with prs as 
    ( select abc.entity_id
             , abc.cust_code
      from abc
           join def
           on abc.entity_title = def.entity_title
      where def.in_count != def.out_quant
      group by abc.entity_id, abc.cust_code having count(*) > 1 
     )
   , ent as 
    ( select distinct abc.entity_title
               , listagg(abc.entity_title) 
                     within group (order by abc.entity_title)
                     over (partition by prs.entity_id, prs.cust_code) as cmp_entity_title
      from abc
           join prs
    on abc.entity_id = prs.entity_id
    and abc.cust_code = prs.cust_code  
     )
select distinct abc.entity_id   
       , ent.cmp_entity_title
       , abc.cust_code
from ent
    join abc
    on abc.entity_title = ent.entity_title   
order by abc.entity_id  
         , abc.cust_code
/
```

Please note that the output is *strongly dependent* on the initial condition of the data.  If you look at my [inevitable SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0fe3/1), you will see I have included additional rows into the set-up.

The first commented out ABC record ...

```
/* insert into abc values ('AB101Z','BAN','101Z',     5151         );  */
```

.. creates a matched triple, `BANINDPAK`, which replaces all occurrences of BAN, IND or PAK.  This is a logical outcome of your rules and one which I assume you expect.

The other commented out ABC record ...

```
/* insert into abc values ('JK101X','TIB','101K',     3434         );  */
```

... creates a second matched pair, `PAKTIB`, whose presence generates multiple results for the PAK entity's records.  This is also a logical outcome of your rules but perhaps a less-expected one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but output is not desired.Query is not including below row in output :

**CD101Y |  INDPAK | 101Y**

INDPAK is replacement for all the records whether those are for IND and PAK both or for any of those two

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e9cc/6) is something that might help you :

```
select * from 
(
  select t1.entity_id, case when t1.entity_title in('IND','PAK') then 'INDPAK' else t1.entity_title end as entity_title, t1.cust_code
  from   abc t1 join def t2
  on     t1.entity_title = t2.entity_title
  where  t2.in_count <> t2.out_count

) t
group by t.entity_id, t.entity_title, t.cust_code
```

Comment: This only works by hard-coding the INDPAK summary, but seems undesirable.  Although as the question is framed vaguely, so it might be the right answer :)

Comment: Apologies for ambiguity..:(
@user2315555 Thanks for your reply.Fiddle is showing the desired output but parameters have been hard coded in query.How can I format this query to remove hard coding.

Comment: you mean you have some more `entity_title` similar to IND/PAK and you want to concatenate all of them? for e.g there is one more entry in abc `AB101Z  AUS  101Z  1214` then you want resulting row as `AB101Z  AUSINDPAK  101Z`.

Comment: @user2315555..No I don't want more concatenation..just one concern that name of parameters(IND,PAK) have been hard coded in query itself..same as APC has mentioned in his comment.